# Repainting with values in LinkedStack not working

Tags: java, user-interface, canvas

I am making a game, and whenever I'm going to press the new game button, my canvas doesn't update, but my LinkedStack values have already been updated. It's supposedly have shuffled the LinkedStack values.

### [EDIT]

-added a few parts in my code, and the main problem in my code is that whenever I press new game, the nodes show the correct new value, but whenever it is passed to paint(g) (or repaint()), the nodes still houses the first values.

This is a part of my canvas code. (This class extends Canvas)

```
public class Solitaire extends Canvas{
public Solitaire(){
    setSize(width, height);
    //initializes specific LinkedStacks
    //creates "cards"
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paintSolitaire(g2d);
}
public void paintSolitaire(Graphics2D g2d){
    int i=0;
    int move=0;
    LinkedStack temp=null;

    ypos=0;
    xpos=30;
    while(i!=7){
        ypos=220;
        move=30;
        temp=new LinkedStack();
        while(tableau[i].peek()!=null){
            temp.push(tableau[i].pop());
        }

        if(temp.peek()==null){
            g2d.drawRect(xpos, ypos, 70, 95);
        }
        else{
            tableauNode=temp.checkTop();
            while(tableauNode!=null){
                Card card=(Card)tableauNode.data;
                if(card.getFaceUp()==true){
                    ypos=ypos+move;
                    g2d.drawImage(getImage("Deck/"+card.getImage()+".png"), xpos, ypos, 70, 95, null);
                }
                else if(card.getFaceUp()==false){
                    ypos=ypos+move;
                    g2d.drawImage(getImage("Deck/155.png"), xpos, ypos, 70, 95, null);
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
                tableauNode=tableauNode.link;
            }
        }
        while(temp.peek()!=null){
            tableau[i].push(temp.pop());
        }
        temp=null;
        tableauNode=null;
        i++;
        xpos=xpos+100;
    }
    g2d.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 30)); 
    g2d.drawString(occurence, 800, 125);
}
public void update(){
    repaint();
}
public void deal(){
    //deals "cards" into specific LinkedStack
}
public void shuffle(){
    //shuffles LinkedList nodes
}
```

This is part of my main class that implements JFrame. This block of code executes once I press "New Game".

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private Solitaire solitaire;
private JPanel panel;
public Main(){
    panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(this.createMenuBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    solitaire=new Solitaire();

    solitaire.shuffle();
    solitaire.deal();
    panel.add(solitaire, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel);
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
}
private JMenuBar createMenuBar(){
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu;
    JMenuItem newGame;
    menu=new JMenu("Menu");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    newGame=new JMenuItem("New Game");
    newGame.addActionListener(this);
    menu.add(newGame);
    return menuBar;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String command=e.getActionCommand();
    switch (command){
        case "New Game":
        solitaire=new Solitaire();
        solitaire.shuffle();
        solitaire.deal();
        solitaire.update();
        break;
    }
}
public static void main (String[] args){
    Main main=new Main();
}
}
```

Comment: Problems: 1) You should call the super's painting method, here `paint(g)`, within an override of a painting method, else house-keeping painting is not done. 2) You should never read in images from within a painting method or do anything that takes appreciable time as doing this can slow down or freeze the application -- why re-read images when you only need to read them once. 3) You're trying to do too many things together, making for code that is hard to debug. Separate out concerns, including testing reading in and displaying images, so code can be separately debugged....

Comment: 4) You shouldn't be extending Canvas but rather JPanel, and then override its paintComponent method, not its paint method. 5) When asking about why your code doesn't work, you should create and post a [mcve] so we can test said code, and thus be able to help you.

Comment: edited a few parts in my code. I hope it helps :) 

The main problem in my code is that whenever I press new game, the nodes show the correct new value, but whenever it is passed to paint(g) (or repaint()), it still houses the first values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String command=e.getActionCommand();
    switch (command){
        case "New Game":
        solitaire=new Solitaire();
        solitaire.shuffle();
        solitaire.deal();
        solitaire.update();
        break;
    }
}
```

You're creating a new Solitaire object but not displaying it anywhere. The original Solitaire object sits in your GUI unchanged.

Options:

- Remove the original Solitaire object and add the new one to the GUI
- Then call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container that holds it.
- Even better, improve Solitaire so that you don't have to create a new one but rather simply call `reset()` on the original one and it shuffles and renews itself.
- Again, don't use Canvas but rather JPanel, don't override paint but rather paintComponent, and call the super's painting method.

Comment: how would I remove the original object? and how do I add it to the GUI?

Comment: @medyormandy: how did you add it originally? There's a corresponding `remove(...)` method. I think that one mistake you're making is that you're thinking that by changing the object that the solitaire variable refers to that your GUI should magically update itself, but that is not so. Changing the object that the variable refers to will have no effect on the object that is displayed in the GUI. It's the basic difference between object and variable that you're going to need to work to understand.

Comment: I went on to just improve Solitaire and made a `reset()` function, and it's now working as it should. Thank you so much!